# MVC3 jquery popup resuable view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to reuse the popup.cshtml when ever i click the actionlink on index.cshtml page. When i click the category id action link, i can see the popup with 2 textboxes and submit button, which inserts data into category dropdown.

I want the same popup coming up when jobid action link is clicked, but insert into jobid dropdown.

Please help me

Index.cshtml

```
 <td>
       @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID")
       @Html.ActionLink("New test", "Popup", "Home", null, new { @class = "openPopup", data_dialog_id = "popuplDialog", data_dialog_title = "Add New" })
     </td>
    <td>
       @Html.DropDownList("JobID")
       @Html.ActionLink("New", "Popup", "Home", null, new { @class = "openPopup", data_dialog_id = "popuplDialog", data_dialog_title = "Popup" })
     </td>
```

Popup.cshtml

```
@model MVC3.Models.ValidationModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Popup";
Layout = null;
}
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#subbutton').live("click", function () {
        var code = $("#txtCode").val();
        var value = $
        var characterReg = /^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/;
        if (!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
            $('#codelbl').text("*");
            return false;
        }
        if (!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
            $('#codelbl').text("*");
            return false;
        }
        //            $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        //            alert("test1");
    });

});
</script>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label> Code</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.TextBox("txtCode")
        <label id="codelbl" style="color:Red"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>

           @Html.TextBox("txtName")
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="subbutton" type="submit" value="Insert" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the ID of the dropdown you want to insert into on the parent page when you click the link using JavaScript, before you open the popup.

Then on the subbutton click event, read the value of what to insert into from that hidden input and act accordingly.

Comment: what should i use for the hidden input?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" id="hdnDropdownSelector" />` and just set its value using JavaScript; then read it and use that selector for the dropdown on the subbutton click event